# plotly Sunburst charts not making full circles

Tags: python, plotly

I am using plotly graph_objects to create a Sunburst chart to visualize some hierarchical data, however in my current chart:

[image: Current plot]

each parent (Complete score, Ecological, Economical and Social) has an additional empty wedge, which I dont want.

Here are the lists I use to generate the chart (put into a dataframe for ease of reading):

[image: Inputs]

And the code:

```
fig = Figure()

fig.add_trace(Sunburst(
    labels=labels,
    parents=parents,
    values=values,
    text=scores,
    marker=dict(
        colors=scores,
        colorscale='tealgrn',
        cmid=0),
    hovertemplate='<b>%{label} </b> <br> Score: %{text}',
    name='Visualization Criteria Catalogue'
    ))

fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=0, l=0, r=0, b=0))
```

My ideal output would be the same plot, just without the empty spaces.

Comment: I'm guessing if you just remove `values = values`, you'll get the plot you're looking for. If your question was reproducible, I could help a lot more. A picture of your data is pretty useless. Where did scores come from?  If that doesn't help--- If you used a pandas data frame, extract the data with `pd.DataFrame.to_dict` and copy the output exactly as it appears. If you used base Python data structures, try `repr` (no import needed).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with add_trace that you have in your code.  However, I was experiencing the same issue as you and what fixed my chart was to add `branchvalues='total'` to the sunburst figure as below.  I have no data anywhere named 'total', it is a setting of sorts.  For reference on why this works and a better explanation, see [this page in the plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/#sunburst-of-a-rectangular-dataframe-with-discrete-color-argument-in-pxsunburst), which states:

> values: sets the values associated with sunburst sectors, determining their width (See the branchvalues section below for different modes for setting the width).

And:

> Note that this means that the sum of the values of the children cannot exceed the value of their parent when branchvalues is set to "total". When branchvalues is set to "remainder" (the default), children will not take up all of the space below their parent (unless the parent is the root and it has a value of 0).

```
import plotly.express as px

data = dict(
labels=["carbon-free", "carbon", "wind", "solar", "hydro", "thermal", "coal"],
parents=["", "", "carbon-free", "carbon-free", "carbon-free", "carbon", "carbon"],
percentage=[carbon_free_total, carbon_total, wind, solar, hydro, thermal, coal],
)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = px.sunburst(
    df,
    labels=df['labels'],
    names=df['labels'],
    parents=df['parents'],
    values=df['percentage'],
    branchvalues='total',
)
```

I am using plotly express, but I believe this will work for plotly graphing objects as well, since that is what they are using in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same thing as @oskar-b, where the `value` is not important, the hierarchy relationship visualization is what we want to achieve.

Answer by @catbyte-io gives the hints on `branchvalues='total'` VS `'branchvalues='remaining'`, the second one is the default one. The width of each element equals its own `value` plus sums of all its children. When we set every element's value as `1`, the parent width will always exceed sum of its children by 1

A MEW

```
import plotly.express as px
data = dict(
    character=["Eve", "Mike", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
    parent=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" ],
    value=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

fig = px.sunburst(
    data,
    names='character',
    parents='parent',
    values='value',
)
fig.show()
```

This will yield similar thing like @oskar-b

[image]

However if we make some modification of the `value` array, makes each non-leaf node as 0, a full cycle will get made

```
import plotly.express as px
data = dict(
    character=["Eve", "Mike", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
    parent=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" ],
    value=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

# Iteration to make non-leaf node's value become 0 instead of 1
for i in range(len(data['character'])):
    target = data['character'][i]
    if data['parent'].count(target) != 0:
        data['value'][i] = 0

fig = px.sunburst(
    data,
    names='character',
    parents='parent',
    values='value',
)
fig.show()
```

[image]